# Banned words but not if with more words

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, words, restrict

I find solution, to ban some words if they are entered in input field.
The problem is that i need ban them only when somebody use them as single word, not when are entered with more words.

Example:

If %bannedword% was entered then ERROR must show up, but if somebody write

" %bannedword% wordnotbanned "

all must be marked as correct input fill, without any ERROR.

What i must do to everything works fine?

Here is the jQuery

```
$('#submit').click(function() {

var bannedWords = ["black", "white"],
regex = new RegExp('\\b' + bannedWords.join("\\b|\\b") + '\\b', 'i');
var zalvalid = !regex.test($('#zalmie').val().toLowerCase());

if(!zalvalid) {

    $('#zwynik').addClass("hover").html('<strong>ERROR:</strong>');
    $('#zalmie').focus();
    return false;

} else {

    $('#zwynik').addClass("hover").html('<strong>NICE ONE!</strong>');

}

});
```

and **here is the Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/p16954wc/

Comment: `"What i must do to everything works fine?"` - Well, for starters, you could identify some way in which it currently *doesn't* work.

Comment: Why you people thumbs down this question? If you dont know how to help just please don't disturb

What is wrong with you @@David, i have a question so i'm ask. What is wrong with this question?

Comment: When You entered the banned word with other words the ERROR is appears. I want that the ERROR not appear in this case... ERROR must showup only if single banned word was entered
||| black - > ERROR ; this is black - > CORRECT ; white black - > ERROR

Comment: OK. I understand. But the list of banned words will be longer. So i need the code that will make the banned words can be added simply by the add each new in ["black","white"] part of code

Answer (score -1):

I have changed the bannedwords array, that will be used for regExp.
You must also include the scenario to handle witespaces. So I have added thoes in bannedWords array.

```
$('#submit').click(function() {

    var bannedWords = ["black ", "white ", "black", "white"],
    regex = new RegExp('\\b' + bannedWords.join("\\b|\\b") + '\\b', 'i');
    var zalvalid = !regex.test($('#zalmie').val().toLowerCase());

if(!zalvalid) {
    $('#zwynik').addClass("hover").html('<strong>ERROR:</strong>');
    $('#zalmie').focus();
    return false;
    } else {
    $('#zwynik').addClass("hover").html('<strong>NICE ONE!</strong>');
    }

});
```

Here's [a link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayurRahul/6g8br2wd/1/)!

Earlier, you were not able to handle the scenario where:
Example : black something.
So, You must have regExp which must be able to validate "black " and "white " .

If your list of banned word is long , then just add extra space after each word.

You can also automate you banWord array creation.

Comment: `Updated you code` is not an answer if people have to use a diff tool to figure out what was changed. Explain what was changed and why

Comment: @charlietfl: yeah Sure charlie, got you. Hope I am clear now :)

Comment: @X9DESIGN : you got it brother.   ??