# jquery block words from list if used as single word, not when with others

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, cpu-word, restrict

I must try one more time in here with this problem. 
As I could notice, resolve my problem is not so simple. 
I have input text field in which some words from specified list can't be used, but only when the each word from list is entered as single, not with other words.

So i define 'var'

```
var bannedWords = ["black", "white", "red", "blue"],
```

Now when somebody enter any word from list above, should see error message.
But more important is the case when he enter any word from list above with any other and then this must be accepted.

In short, when somebody enter:

---

"black" - ERROR,

"this is black" - ACCEPTED,

"white is cool" - ACCEPTED,

"this is red color" - ACCEPTED

---

Very important is that i need to be able simply add any each other word to this list, so everything still could act.

I try to find help [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974314/banned-words-but-not-if-with-more-words), but i think no one understand me, or was not able to help.
Is anyone who can give me a tip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be optimized .. but: http://jsfiddle.net/1819tb2m/

```
var badWords = ["black", "white", "red", "blue"];

$("input").keyup(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < badWords.length; i++)
    {
        if(this.value == badWords[i])
        {
            $("p").text("BAD WORD!");
            return;
        }        
    }
    $("p").text("accepted " + this.value);
})
```

Comment: Are You kidding me? :D You are mad guy :) This solution ROCKS! Oh man, how i love you! :P I'm still to stupid :) ACCEPTED!

Comment: part of modifying badWords collection not solved. Solution is't complete. Also add some trimming to prevent inserting spaces in beginning.

Comment: you can always use indexOf in javascript to check if an item exists in an array and no need to use for loop too bad my answer was voted down, maybe because I didn't give a fancy one by including input and other stuff

Comment: @X9DESIGN hehe glad I could help :) You could optimize it a bit by checking on case sensitive words. So  "BLACK" is also "black"

Comment: @andrex I wasn't the down-voter, but [`indexOf` on arrays doesn't work below IE 9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). If we knew OP didn't need to support IE it would've been the best answer.

Comment: @andrex: Your solution also did not allow for `"white is cool" == valid` example. I was about to also down-vote when you deleted it :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie are you sure it did not allow?  it allows white is cool since it's not on the array of words. See again for yourself http://jsfiddle.net/ph99mgv6/2/

Comment: @MortenOC yes, and i do that by using .toLowerCase() - but the main problem is resolved
 || 
but exactly i needed this - http://jsfiddle.net/1819tb2m/1/ - Thank You one more time!!!

Comment: @Shai I just run it on my XP machine with compatibility to IE 8 why did it ever work if it's not compatible? I wonder

Comment: Here with case sensitive... "black" is also "BLACK" - verified by button click action --- http://jsfiddle.net/1819tb2m/2/

Comment: @andrex If it works in IE 8 compatibility mode then that's a bug in IE compatibility mode. Try it in actual IE 8 and you'll see.